# How to run system() with C#?

Tags: c#, system

I'm rewriting a Ruby program in C#. It has a lot of system() calls (like system("./program")).

Is there a way to call it in C#, or do I have to use Systemm.Diagnostics.Process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[System.Diagnostics.Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) is the .NET equivalent to `system()` in Ruby.

> or do I have to use Systemm.Diagnostics.Process?

You can add `using System.Diagnostics;` at the top of your file.  It then just becomes `Process.Start("program.exe");`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to bother with splitting up the arguments and set up the `ProcessStartInfo`, you can simply add a reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly and use [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Shell` static method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.shell.aspx).

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

Interaction.Shell("format c: /q");
```